# How to hide a row in tree view?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I want to hide a row based on a condition.The tree view is one2many field.If the `od_state = cancel`,then the row should be invisible
code:

```
<field name="line_id">
<tree editable='bottom' >
      <field name="name" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','cancel')]}"/>
      <field name="date" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','cancel')]}"/>
      <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
</tree>
</field>
```

The above code hides the data in line(row),but the line is still visible.

Output:

[image]

Comment: There is no possibility to hide a row in One2many field tree view. You can only make it readonly.

Comment: Based in @sfx's comment, you could try to building two trees view and show one or other depending on your conditions.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo's suggestion would be best

Answer (score 0):

You can hide rows of a tree by adding a domain on the ir.actions.act_window

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="id_name">
      <field name="name">name</field>
      <field name="res_model">res.model</field>
      <field name="domain">[('state', '=', 'cancel')]</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```